# Can an HttpModule raise events?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, httpmodule

I have registered an HttpModule in web.config and I want it to raise an event to a controller in my application.  In the controller I need to register my event handler.

```
mod.EventName += HandleEvent;
```

How do I get the concrete class of my module?

In Init() of the module I tried:

```
context.Application["Key"] = this;
```

Then in the controller:

```
var mod = (ModuleType)requestContext.HttpContext.Application.Get("Key");
```

but that doesn't seem to give me the concrete class. When the module tries to raise the event, handler is null.

```
protected virtual void OnMyEvent(MyEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<MyEventArgs> handler = EventName;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
}
```

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: The module detects that a user has logged in twice on two different sessions.  The event alerts the application so that the application can SignOut() one of the logins and redirect appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Get the instance of the module in Initialize() of the controller like so:

```
            _mod = (ModuleType)requestContext.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Modules.Get("ModuleName");
```

Then you can wire up your events.